# String index out of range on SQL insert (python)

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I'm currently writing a python script to insert information in to an MS SQL Server. And I am receiving this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\....", line 31, in <module>
    sql_command = format_str.format(ID=i[0],Start_time=i[1],Completion_time=i[2],Email=i[3],Name=i[4],Team=i[5],Jurisdiction=i[6],Caught_up=i[7],
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I believe I am misunderstanding something fundamental.

Below is my code (I've blocked out a few things and added some ellipses since its work-related and contains personal info):

```
for i in df:
    format_str = """INSERT INTO DB (ID,Start_time,Completion_time,...)                
                     VALUES ({ID},'{Start_time}','{Completion_time}'...)
                ;"""
    sql_command=format_str.format(ID=i[0],Start_time=i[1],
                                  Completion_time=i[2],...)
    cursor.execute(sql_command)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I'm wondering if this may have something to do with some of my values, say email in row 3 being empty?

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the value of `i` within the for loop and see if it an array as you are expecting?

I suspect it to be a string and you are indexing it to a value that is not there.

Check this example:

```
In [1]: data = 'string'

In [2]: data[5]
Out[2]: 'g'

In [3]: data[6]  # this is out of bounds!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-bd176b01b336> in <module>()
----> 1 data[6]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Also, if you want to iterate through a pandas dataframe, try this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # save index as your ID if that fits your requirement.
    print(row['column_1'], row['column_2'])
```

Comment: Can you paste what you tried? If it is a KeyError, can you check the keys available? “print df.columns” will show you the available columns you can access.

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...", line 33, in <module>
    row['False_alarms'],row['Emails'],row['Spreadsheets'],row['Special_tasks'],row['Reports'],row['Roadblocks'])
KeyError: 'ID''                                                                                                            
    Index(['ID', 'Start_time', 'Completion_time'..]) is what I got for the print df.columns.

Comment: You do not have ID as a column. If you want to use the index as ID, you can use the “index” variable you get as a part of iterrows(). See my edit in the answer.

Comment: Index(['ID', 'Start_time', 'Completion_time'..]) is what I got for the print df.columns.

Comment: Still, you get a KeyError for 'ID'?

Comment: Correct. I decided to create the INSERT String a different way, avoiding this problem. (Bringing up some new ones however)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the problem is in the way you access the pandas data frame.  For eg. Let us consider a sample dataframe,

```
temp = {'string' : ['text1', 'text10', 'text123'], 'string1': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']}
```

when you do iteration as in your code,

```
for i in temp:
  print (i)
```

The 'i' here, will have the value of the column names in the pandas frame and not the actual values of the row.  And so, if the column name is 'string', i[0] is 's', i[1] is 't' and so on.  And that's why you are getting `string index out of range error`.

To iterate the rows, and get the values instead of columns,  change your code to

```
for index, i in df.iterrows():
  format_str = """INSERT INTO DB (ID,Start_time,Completion_time,...)

                 VALUES ({ID},'{Start_time}','{Completion_time}'...)
            ;"""
  sql_command=format_str.format(ID=i[0],Start_time=i[1],
                              Completion_time=i[2],...)
  cursor.execute(sql_command)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Does this have any limitations for data types?

Comment: Here, we are only fetching the row values through iteration and no manipulation is done.  So, no data type based limitation if I understood your question correctly.